# Why is SQL Server converting my decimal parameter 12.50 to 12.49999999

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, parameter-passing, decimal

I am passing a decimal value from C# to a SQL Server stored procedure.

The parameter in the stored procedure is defined as `@latitude decimal`. Right before going into the stored procedure, the value is 25.631230

When running the profiler I can see that SQL Server sees the value as: 25.631229999999999

This is obviously a much different value when you are dealing with longitude/latitude.

```
SqlParameter lat = new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal, Value = 25.631230, ParameterName = "@latitude" };

cmd.Parameters.Add(lat);
cmd.CommandText = storedProcName;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Hope it's just a setting somewhere ;)

Comment: What is the C# data type? Add the C# code with the SqlParameter definition to your question.

Comment: You are aware that `decimal` without any further details is equivalent to `decimal(18,0)` which means **no digits** after the decimal point?

Comment: Added c#. If decimal(18,0) means no digits, why does it still have digits?

Comment: `System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal` will [infer the scale and precision from the value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.precision?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#remarks) so when you look at it in profiler you won't see this truncation. You will still get it when the stored proc uses that value though if the parameter datatype doesn't allow any scale > 0. The parameter datatype should be something like `@latitude decimal (8,6)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the precision in the stored procedure "decimal(18, 15)" was the correct solution. After I did that another error popped up that was confusing me but turns out it was unrelated to this specific question.

Thanks all that pointed me in the right direction.